# How do I provide a field storage definition for hook_entity_bundle_field_info?

Tags: 8

The [documentation says](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info/8.2.x):

> Bundle fields either have to override an existing base field, or need to provide a field storage definition via hook_entity_field_storage_info() unless they are computed.

How can I do that?

I tried something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_storage_info().
 */
function km_mod_entity_field_storage_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    $definitions['field_metatags'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('metatag')
      ->setName('field_metatags')
      ->setLabel(t('Metatags'))
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(1)
      ->setTargetEntityTypeId($entity_type->id());
    return $definitions;
  }
}


/**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_field_info().
 */
function km_mod_entity_bundle_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {

  if ($entity_type->id() === 'node') {
    $fields = [];

    $fields['field_metatags'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('metatag')
      ->setLabel(t('Metatags'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'metatag',
        'weight' => 50,
      ));

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

It does not work as intended though. The field does not appear during Form display, and when trying to save:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Table mapping contains invalid field field_metatags. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()
```

I've checked the field storage config yaml (by creating the field manually) and it doesn't really look any difference to how I try to configure it:

```
uuid: 4c6ecbd5-49b3-4305-8f47-518f76a917f7
langcode: sv
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - metatag
    - node
id: node.field_yaay
field_name: field_yaay
entity_type: node
type: metatag
settings: {  }
module: metatag
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

I have run `drush entity-updates` as well, with no luck.

**So what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It looks like there might be a problem with Core.

[This patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/core-entity-sql-content-entity-storage-2583111-1_0.patch) attached to the issue "[Hook entity_field_storage_info is broken](https://www.drupal.org/node/2584729)" fixed things for me.

Comment: Please QA-review the edit I applied to your answer, feel free to further improve it, or just rollback if you don't like it at all. BTW: the downvote is not mine ...

Answer (score 1):

For fix this error i created a class *FieldStorageDefinition*

```php
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;

class FieldStorageDefinition extends BaseFieldDefinition {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isBaseField() {
    return FALSE;
  }

}
```

for created the fields use the class **FieldStorageDefinition** not **BaseFieldDefinition**

```php
$fields['field_metatags'] = FieldStorageDefinition::create('metatag')
```